# Django 3.0.5 ModelForm has no model class specified. Error

Tags: python, django

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        models = User
        feilds = ['username','email','password']

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = UserProfileInfo
        feilds = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yghoi.png)

As you can see in the above error image, my code is not functioning properly. I have added my forms.py and models.py code. Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `model` instead of `models` inside the Meta class of UserForm.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User # model instead of models here
        feilds = ['username','email','password']
```